# Checking the possibility to store passwords with Java keytool

Tags: keytool

In Java 8 the option -importpassword was added to keytool. It works with JKECS storetype:
    $ keytool -importpassword -storetype JCEKS -alias alias
    Enter the password to be stored:
    Re-enter password:

```
$keytool -list -storetype JCEKS -keypass "" -keystore mystore.jceks

Keystore type: JCEKS
Keystore provider: SunJCE

Your keystore contains 1 entry

alias, Apr 7, 2016, SecretKeyEntry,
```

Trying to extract it, I get the error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <alias> has no certificate
```

My question is: How do I extract the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `keytool` is lacking the capability to extract/export the password imported using the `-importpass` command. But you can view the password using `KeyStore` api, using the below code:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
ks.load(new FileInputStream(new File("KEYSTORE_FILE")), "KEYSTORE_PASSWORD".toCharArray());

SecretKey passwordKey = (SecretKey) ks.getKey("ALIAS", "KEY_PASSWORD".toCharArray());

System.out.println(new String(passwordKey.getEncoded()));
```

Comment: @ZivHarpaz - If this solved your issue, you can mark the answer as accepted, so others facing the same issue will know the solution.